# "List index out of range" on 3D array of objects

Tags: python, class, multidimensional-array, pickle, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm just simply trying to store a bunch of blocks in a bunch of chunks. It's for a very simple voxel world. There are three class levels at the moment in the test code (I was going to play around with the pickle module and serializing): the world, chunks in the world, and blocks in the chunks.

This is the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:/Crayder/Scripts/pickle 
test/pickle1.py", line 27, in <module>    aWorld = world();  File 
"C:/Crayder/Scripts/pickle test/pickle1.py", line 25, in __init__    
self.chunks[cX][cY] = chunk(cX, cY);  File "C:/Crayder/Scripts/pickle 
test/pickle1.py", line 18, in __init__    self.blocks[bX][bY][bZ] = 
block((self.x * 16) + bX, (self.y * 16) + bY, bZ); IndexError: list 
index out of range
```

And here is the code:

```
class block:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, data = 0):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
        self.z = z;
        self.data = data;

class chunk:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
        self.blocks = [];
        for bX in range(16):
            for bY in range(16):
                for bZ in range(64):
                    self.blocks[bX][bY][bZ] = block((self.x * 16) + bX, (self.y * 16) + bY, bZ);

class world:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chunks = [];
        for cX in range(16):
            for cY in range(16):
                self.chunks[cX][cY] = chunk(cX, cY);

aWorld = world();

print(aWorld.chunks[2][2].blocks[2][2][2]);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are working with a `list`, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating empty lists and then trying to assign into them.  The error you're getting is the same as

```
l = [] 
l[0] = 'something'  # raises IndexError because len(l) == 0
```

You have to either append elements to the list:

```
l = []
l.append('something')
```

or prepopulate the lists so that you can then replace the elements:

```
l = list(range(5))
l[4] = 'last element'
```

For your two dimensional case:

```
self.chunks = list(range(16))
for cX in range(16):
    self.chunks[cX] = list(range(16))
    for cY in range(16):
        self.chunks[cX][cY] = chunk(cX, cY)
```

which you can extrapolate to the three dimensional case.

Comment: This is correct, except I'm using Python 3.5.2. The range function literally returns a 'range' iterable object. So for those using 3+, use the list class (i.e. instead of `range(16)` use `list(range(16))`).

Comment: You're right (I use 2.7).  Edited answer (using list comprehensions instead of list()).